# c++ inheritance and constructors

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor

```
class A {
public:
      A(int i): data(i) {cout << "A::A(" << i << ")" << endl;}
      A(const char* s): data(0) { cout << "A::A(" << s << ")"<< endl;}
      ~A() { cout << "A::~A()" << endl;}
private:
int data;
};

class B:public A {
public:
    B(const A& a): A(a){ std::cout << "B::B(const A& a)" << std::endl;}
     ~B() { std::cout << "B::~B()" << std::endl;}
};

int main() {
    B b0(0);
    B b1("abc");
return 0;
}
```

Pretty straightforward, can someone explain why the output is :

```
 A::A(0)
 B::B(const A& a)
 A::~A()
 A::A(abc)
 B::B(const A& a)
 A::~A()
 B::~B()
 A::~A()
 B::~B()
 A::~A()
```

Comment: what part do you not understand?

Comment: @user504377: It is better to make this kind of question more specific by explaining what output you where expecting, and how it differs from what you are actually getting.

Answer (score 5):

`B b0(0);` - there's no such constructor for B, so the compiler is looking for some constructor, that can be called with just one cast (one implicit cast is allowed, 2 are not), so it finds `B::B(const A& a)`, because `A` has a constructor with only one parameter, and this is `A::A(int i)`. This means, that 0 can be casted to `int`, so temporary `A` object is created (and destroyed, after B is created). So, here's why we have

```
 A::A(0)
 B::B(const A& a)
 A::~A()
```

Then the next is called: `B b1("abc");`, so here comes:

```
 A::A(abc)
 B::B(const A& a)
 A::~A()
```

This is absolutely the same as with `int`, but here with `char*`.

Then, both objects are destructed, so their destructors are called in the opposite order, as their constructors are called, that's where

```
 B::~B()
 A::~A()
 B::~B()
 A::~A()
```

comes from.

It looks confising, because you haven't overloaded `A::A( const A& a)` and you don't see, that it is called 2 times, too.

Cheers (:

---

A small edit: not `A::A()`, but `A::A( const A& a)` - thanks to Nim.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have a default constructor for `B`, so the compiler finds the best alternatives (i.e. construct `A` first with the matching inputs and then construct `B` from that.)

sequence would be:

- construct temporary `A` with `int`
- construct `B` with this `A`
- destroy that `A`
- (you don't have a copy constructor for `A`, else you'd see that thrown in there too!)
- same for string
- then sequence of base class/derived class destructors.

Comment: that's the temporary that is required to call the conversion constructor of `B`

Comment: The argument you are passing to the constructor of `B` is not passed through to `A`. In is implicitly converted to a temporary `A`, that is then passed to the copy constructor of `A`. When the constructor of `B` exits, this temporary gets destroyed.

Comment: Why is the copy c-tor of A called? B is constructed with reference to A, not with a copy of A? Am I missing something ?

Comment: @Kiril, I mentioned that because the base `A` is constructed via the copy constructor in the OP's code.

Answer (score 1):

A temporary `A` object is constructed, then passed via a const reference to `B`'s constructor, where it is copied using the copy ctor (which you haven't augmented with debug output, so you can't see it) into the `B` object.

Destruction takes place in reverse order of construction; the temporaries are destroyed when the constructor which they were passed to is finished.

Answer (score 1):

It constructs a temporary A with the argument in the B constructor which it uses to initialise B::A (via the default copy constructor - hence no output for A::A(const A&))
The temporary A is destroyed after the call to B::B is complete.

Answer (score 1):

```
 1.  A::A(0)          <- temporary A in B b0(0) line
 2.  B::B(const A& a) <- construct b0, no visible call to A as you did not provide A(A const &)
 3.  A::~A()          <- destroy temporary A created in line 1        
 4.  A::A(abc)        <- temporary A in B b1("abc") line
 5.  B::B(const A& a) <- construct b1, no visible call to A as you did not provide A(A const &)
 6.  A::~A()          <- destroy temporary A created in line 4
 7.  B::~B()          <- b1 ~B() destructor
 8.  A::~A()          <- b1 ~A() destructor
 9.  B::~B()          <- b0 ~B() destructor
 10. A::~A()          <- b0 ~A() destructor
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll try:

```
 A::A(0)          // 1: construct an A using A(int) ctor in line 1 of main
 B::B(const A& a) // 2: construct a B passing the previously constructed A by const ref
 A::~A()          // 3: destruct the temporary A made in 1
 A::A(abc)        // 4:  construct an A using A(const char*) ctor in line 2 of main
 B::B(const A& a) // 5: construct a B passing the previously constructed A by const ref
 A::~A()          // 6: destruct the temporary A made in 4
                  // unwind the stack on exit of main
 B::~B()          // destruct B made in main line 2
 A::~A()          // destruct A inherited by B made in main line 2
 B::~B()          // destruct B made in main line 1
 A::~A()          // destruct A inherited by B made in main line 1
```